# Best method to test if the Pi is stable after overclocking

Tags: hardware, overclocking

What is the best method to test if a Pi is stable after overclocking? Primarily the CPU, but also RAM, GPU etc.

Comment: it's not very stable even without the OC, hence the cron reboots, hardware watchdogs and other things to restart the system in case something bad happens.

Comment: In general OC has issues with LAN and Wifi, period  - There is nothing you can about that. OC is good if you want to crunch numbers faster, like say, bitcoin mining and not bothered about anything else. Otherwise.. there is no point as things start to go wrong - even if its stable you are likely to get a reset from time to time cause by `stack overflows` that just cant be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

A very easy and proven way to stress the CPU is to use [cpuburn](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/cpuburn), but the generall testing of stability can only be done over a long period of time. So even if you stress the RPi for x minutes, it doesn't mean your system is 100% stable all the time. I would proceed with caution and incremental steps.

Personally I run my Pi with the highest overclocking setting in raspi-config and have had no problems. But @Winkleink made a good point about the PSU, which is important if you want to have a stable overclocked system. I have mine on a USB-charger with a max. output of 2.1A.

Answer (score 1):

Personally. I run Minecraft as it gives the GTU and CPU a good work out.
Not very scientific but it has worked for me so far.

If you are considering overclocking then make sure you have a good reliable PSU with at least 1.5A @ 5V. The Pi should use less than 1A and other peripherals will use the rest but when over clocking there can be extra power drawn when needed.

Most problems when overclocking are down to a lack of power rather than the reliability of the  Raspberry Pi.

Comment: This has been my experience as well.  I'll have a Pi that can boot and run when connected to my computer, but keeps rebooting when plugged into a powered hub.  Try either using a different power source or use two different power sources (two hubs for example) and see if the stability improves.